# Error message: "-1.99992 cannot be used as a variable"

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages, nonlinear

could anyone please tell me how to fix this: I want to plot the solutions of a coupled ODE:
$\frac{1}{3} u\partial_x ^3 u = \frac{1}{2} \partial_x v; \ \partial_x\left( u \partial_x v - \frac{1}{2} u^2 \partial_x^3 u\right) = v$, with initial behavior expected as, $u(x) = k x + \beta x^2, \ v(x) = -a+k$ as $x\to 0$. Here $k, \beta, a$ are constants. But I chose $a = 1$ just to avoid another unknown and used $x=10^{-10}$ avoiding $x=0$ in the initial condition which might give me nothing. I am getting the following error messages (`DSolve::dsvar`).

```
eqn1 = u[x]*D[v[x], x] ;
eqn2 = 1/2  u[x]^2* D[u[x], {x, 3}];
solution = 
  DSolve[{1/3  u[x]*D[u[x], {x, 3}] == 1/2  D[v[x], x], 
    D[eqn1, x] - D[eqn2, x] == v[x], 
    u[0] == k * 10^{-10} + β *10^{-100}, v[0] == k - 1}, {u, v},
    x];
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[solution, {k, 0, 2}, {β, -2, 2}]], {x, -2, 2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]]
```

Probably it is a very novice question from the programming point of view, but I am new in using Mathematica. Thanks in advance for any help. [image]

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica code, you might get an immediate answer

Comment: Restart your kernel or clear `u` and `v` using `ClearAll[u]` and `ClearAll[v]`: this error is archetypical for `NDSolve` when the function variables hae assigned values which usally happens if one enters `=` (Set) instead of `==` (Equals) in the list of equations handed to `NDSolve`.

Comment: @N0va I used ClearAll[u], ClearAll[v], but the error is still showing.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have provided the screenshot of my code, isn't it visible ?

Comment: People cannot copy code from images. All evidence so far points towards a mistakenly assigned variable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing that out, didn't realize that. Now I have added it as a code.

Comment: Notice that DSolve returns unevaluated (i.e. it can't solve the problem). To understand what goes wrong, *always* look at intermediate results.

Comment: Can Wolfram come up with a more informative error message for this?  It confuses people all the time!

Comment: Your system has several features indicating a solution is unlikely: high order, system, nonlinear, and the highest order derivatives of `u` and `v` occur in the second equation and not in the first which means they do not depend on the lower order derivatives. Minor syntax complication: Don't use `{}` for grouping. Use only parentheses `()`. The IC `k*10^{-10} + \[Beta]*10^{-100}` evaluates to a 1-vector, which makes `u` represent a vector, while `v` will be a scalar. Fixing it does not solve your problem, though.

Comment: @ChrisK I think their reasoning for not showing an error might be that the line between a case like this and a simple `Sign[x]` is blurry. `Sign[x]` cannot be computed because we do not have enough information about `x`. What should the system do? Throw an error, or leave it as it is until enough information becomes available (e.g. a number is substituted for `x`, or assumptions are given)? I am not arguing one way or another, just pointing out that there are arguments in favour of leaving such expressions unevaluated. I can certainly see arguments against this behaviour too.

Comment: @Szabolcs I took Chris to mean that the message could read something like this: "DSolve::dsvar: 1.2` cannot be used as a variable; perhaps you assigned a value to a variable or are using the command inside another one like Plot."

Comment: @MichaelE2 That point is actually very well explained in the documentation. Click the (...) next to the message and go to the doc page. What I am annoyed about is that now we have to click that (...) and most new users never do. There used to be a much clearer `>>` link to the right of messages. With the new message design we no longer have that. Thus, people no longer read error doc pages. Since people don't read these pages, developers don't add them nearly as often anymore ... In the end, UX suffers badly due to a seemingly tiny decision to hide this important link in the (...) menu.

Comment: @Szabolcs At first I was thinking what MichaelE2 said (which would still be an improvement) but now that I look at it, another suggestion: `*Solve` could issue a warning when they fail: `DSolve: DSolve was unable to solve this system, try NDSolve instead.`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does that mean, I might not able to plot the solutions here ?

Comment: @AmritaGhosh If all you need is plotting, you can solve the equations numerically. `DSolve` is for symbolic solution, `NDSolve` is for numeric solution. `ParametricNDSolve` may also be useful, for easier handling of the parameters `k` and `β`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon @Szabolcs' comment, here's how we can use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to solve this system numerically. After cleaning up the session (`Clear`, `Quit`, etc), the following seems to reproduce the expected behavior at the origin:

```
a = 1
eqn1 = u[x]*D[v[x], x]; 
eqn2 = (1/2)*u[x]^2*D[u[x], {x, 3}]; 
solution = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{(1/3)*u[x]*D[u[x], {x, 3}] == (1/2)*
     D[v[x], x], D[eqn1, x] - D[eqn2, x] == v[x], 
       u[0] == k/10^10 + \[Beta]/10^100, v[0] == k - 1}, {u[x], 
   v[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, {\[Beta], k}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

```
Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[solution[1.1, 1]], {x, -2, 2}]
```

In the picture here, I have plotted the solutions for parameters beta=1.1 and k=1. [image]

Comment: Sorry, but you (and everyone else) should check `solution[1.1, 1]`: Its domain is `{0,0`, that is, `NDSolve` failed to integrate a solution.

Comment: Oh, I see; thanks for pointing that out, @Michael E2. I plotted the desired functional behavior alongside the 2 curves above, and they were, indeed, appropriately tangential to each other, which gave me confidence in the "solution" I had obtained. But you are right; I'll update this post once I get the `InterpolatingFunction`s returned working correctly.

Comment: Hello @ConservedCharge many thanks for your answer.  Would it be possible also to plot the same for a range of k and \beta ?

Answer (score 1):

First bump up the order of the first ODE, so that we can solve for the highest order derivatives, `u''''[x]` and `v''[x]`:

```
ode1 = (1/3)*u[x]*D[u[x], {x, 3}] == (1/2)*D[v[x], x];
ode2 = D[eqn1, x] - D[eqn2, x] == v[x];
newsys = Equal @@@ First@Solve[{D[ode1, x], ode2}, {u''''[x], v''[x]}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {u''''[x] == (2 (3 v[x] - 3 u'[x] v'[x] + u[x] u'[x] u'''[x]))/u[x]^2,
>     v''[x] == (2 (2 v[x] - 2 u'[x] v'[x] + u[x] u'[x] u'''[x]))/u[x]}
> *)
> ```

Then add the missing ICs, taking care to derive the IC for `u'''[0]` from `ode1` the other ICs.

```
ics = Equal @@@ 
   Flatten@NestList[
     u'''[0] -> (u'''[x] /. First@Solve[ode1, u'''[x]] /. 
          x -> 0 /. #) &,
     {u[0] -> k/10^10 + \[Beta]/10^100,
      u'[0] -> up,
      u''[0] -> upp,
      v[0] -> k - 1,
      v'[0] -> vp},
     1];

psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{newsys, ics},
   {u, v}, {x, -2, 2}, {\[Beta], k, up, upp, vp}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];
```

This example develops a singularity at `x = -0.328897`:

```
psol[10^100, 5/4, 1/10^4, 1, 10^2]
Plot[Evaluate@Through[%[x]], {x, -2, 2}]
```

> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == -0.328897, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

[image]